# Can't upload documents to CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to upload documents to my cloudsearch domain through AWS CLI using the following command:

> aws cloudsearchdomain upload-documents --endpoint-url
>   http://doc-domainname-id.region.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch
>   --content-type application/json --documents documents-batch.json

My access policies are open to everyone search and update but i'm still getting an exception when every time i try to upload a batch of documents:

> An error occurred (CloudSearchException) when calling the
>   UploadDocuments operation: Request forbidden by administrative rules.

I've already uploaded files before using the same commands and everything was fine. Now i'm getting this issue.
Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct user? I have two AWS instances I use and by default AWS uses the credentials for the first domain